# SwingWorker - alternative in cases without Swing-Gui

Tags: java, multithreading, swing, swingworker

I really like the `javax.swing.SwingWorker`, it's such a easy way to handle Multithreading.

Now I have a server-application without any GUI and want to use something like the `SwingWorker`, with the `process()`, `done()`, `cancel()`, etc...-methods.

I know I could just use the swing worker and probably have no problem, but still the swing worker obviously is intended to be used together with a swing-application.

So is there anything like the swing worker that is intended to be used in more general cases, but pretty much does the same?

Or if not so, what are the disadvantages of using swing worker and not working with Swing?
What comes to my mind is bad code-style and the `done()` and `process()` - method being executed in the EDT.

Comment: If you're not using Swing, you don't have an EDT (well, at least Swing's EDT, you may have *an* Event Dispatch Thread, but that would be something else then). You don't need `SwingWorker` outside of Swing, since its main utility is being helpful when working **with** Swing. I recommend reading more [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html).

Comment: IMO SwingWorker is not all that much about handling multi-threading. IMO, it is much more about decoupling long action from GUI processing (EDT). It allows you to start a batch job and get the GUI rendered when the batch job has finished. What is the equivalent of GUI rendering in your case? Would https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html  be something to start with?

Answer (score 0):

Most server frameworks expect that you will not attempt to manage threads by yourself. This is usually due to the way they are implemented (resources sur as transactions, security principal, loggers...) might be thread locals. Most of the API are outright not thread-safe, for instance a JDBC connection is not.

For instance the [J2EE restrictions](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/restriction.html) indicate that you should not create or manage threads.

Comment: OP did not state he is using any framework. IMO it is perfectly legal to write server side app with multi-threading based on `java.util.concurrent`.